# Trying to add user settings form fields to database but having trouble

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form where users will define their user settings for a custom application I am building.  This project has introduced me to stmt and I have had to get refamiliar with mysqli.

Currently I am submitting a form with just a couple of "options" defined.  The random echos I have through out my code are getting printed to the screen (for testing) but when I check the database only one of the options gets inserted (the GmailID) option.

The error message on the screen reads as:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/website/public_html/portal/includes/process-user-settings.php on line 56

However, looking over my code there it looks like I have the right amount of variables and parameters.  Like I said, it works for the GmailID but doesnt work for GmailPW and not sure if this error is connected somewhere?  I'm including my code file just in case.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    echo 'Houston we are a go<br />';
    if (isset($_GET['GmailID'], $_GET['GmailPW'], $_GET['userID'])) {

    include_once 'db_connect.php';
    include_once 'psl-config.php';

    $error_msg = "";

    echo 'Info Set<br />';

        $GmailID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'GmailID', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $GmailID = filter_var($GmailID, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

        $GmailPW = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'GmailPW', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if (empty($error_msg)) {
            echo 'No Errors<br />';
            // Create a random salt
            $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));
            echo $random_salt . '<br />';

            // Create salted password 
            $GmailPW = hash('sha512', $GmailPW . $random_salt);
            echo $GmailPW . '<br />';

            $user_id = $_GET['userID'];

            /* OPTIONS */
            $options = array(
                'GmailID' => $GmailID,
                'GmailPW' => $GmailPW
                );

            foreach($options as $key => $value) {
                echo 'Made it to the Foreach <br />';
                // Insert the options into the database 
                if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user_settings (user_id, meta_key, meta_value, salt) VALUES ('$user_id', '$key', '$value', ?)")) {
                    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $user_id, $key, $value, $random_salt);
                    // Execute the prepared query.
                    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                        header('Location: ../index.php?err=insert');
                        exit();
                    }
                }
                echo ' We are done';
                header('Location: ../index.php?user=success');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `(?, ?, ?, ?)` <= try that instead of `('$user_id', '$key', '$value', ?)`. You've defined them in `('ssss', $user_id, $key, $value, $random_salt)`

Comment: Thanks Fred, I did try that previously but then nothing shows up in database under meta_value (in other words GmailID key is set, but value is empty)

Comment: You're welcome. So, `$key` is an array, from the looks of your `foreach`. You'll most likely need to implode it. For example `$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);

foreach($ids as &$val) $val=$db->quote($val);
$in = implode(',',$ids);` taken from one of my test scripts. Not 100% sure if it will work in your case though.

Comment: You can also try something to the effect of, and for example `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $key[0], $key[1]);` another from one of my test scripts and `foreach ($values as $column => $value) {
  $insert_execute[":$column"] = $value;
}`

Comment: Im sorry you lost me, Would you mind providing this as an answer and applying it to what I have above so that I can see what you mean and where I went wrong (and of course accept the answer) In a nutshell Im trying to provide account settings options.  Each option will be a key like GmailID, GmailPW, Profile_pic, etc and then each of those keys will have a value which is the setting for the user they choose.

Comment: Actually I think I just got it :)

Comment: Oh, what did you end up doing?

Comment: You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is flat-out wrong for using placeholders:

```
INSERT [...snip...] ('$user_id', '$key', '$value', ?)")) {
                                                   ^---one single placeholder
```

You have exactly **ONE** placeholder in your query, and 3 directly-inserted variables, which means you're open for SQL injection attacks.

It should be

```
INSERT [...snip...] (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: I tried that but when I do the value never gets inserted for GmailID and any of the values for GmailPW dont get inserted.  With the way I had it previously atleast I was getting the meta_value (users gmail address) inserted with GmailID

Answer (score 1):

Here is what ended up working for me, hope it helps someone else =)

```
$options = array(
            'GmailID' => $GmailID,
            'GmailPW' => $GmailPW,
            'WebmailID' => $WebmailID,
            'WebmailPW' => $WebmailPW,
            'ProfileIMG' => $ProfileIMG
            );

        foreach($options as $key => $value) {

            // Insert the options into the database 
            if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user_settings (user_id, meta_key, meta_value, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $user_id, $key, $value, $random_salt);
                // Execute the prepared query.
                if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                    header('Location: ../index.php?err=insert');
                    exit();
                }
            } 

            //Success
            header('Location: ../index.php?user=success');
            exit();
        }
```